# "resource exhaustive" vs. "exhaustive resource"

Tags: word-order, terminology

Method A exhaust a lot of resources. How can I say this in comparison sentence:

> method A has been viewed as a resource exhaustive compared to method B

Or,

> method A has been viewed as an exhaustive resource compared to method
>   B

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "resource exhaustive"?  It's not wrong, but you haven't given enough context for us to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: If you mean *resource exhaustive* in the sense of *it is something that exhausts resources*, then it's an adjective, not a noun, and there shouldn't be an indefinite article in front of it. (And if you *do* mean it that way, either of the two sentences could be correct. It would depend on exactly what you're trying to express.) You need clarify your question.

Comment: I mean it is something that exhausts resources (e.g. battery).